# Many-To-Many reverse field lookup with ids in Django | Polymorphic Model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, many-to-many

I try to figure out how to produce the correct queryset to retrieve

**url and value fields** (Attr_1 and Attr_2 model)

from querying the **Object1** models 'reverse set' Many-to-Many Relation. Here is my Example:

models.py:

```
class Text(models.Model):
    string = models.TextField()

#Entity
class Element(models.Model):
    pageline = models.IntegerField()

class Object1(Element):
    text = models.ManyToManyField(Text)

class Object2(Element):
    another_var = models.ManyToManyField(Text)
    yet_another = models.CharField(max_length=1)

#Entity
class Attribute(models.Model):
    belongsTo = models.ManyToManyField(Element)

class Attr_1(Attribute):
    url = models.URLField()

class Attr_2(Attribute):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.URLField()
```

If I use:

```
>> models.Object1.objects.get(pk=1).attribute_set.all()                                                                    
<QuerySet [<Attribute: Attribute object (1)>, <Attribute: Attribute object (2)>]>

>> models.Object1.objects.get(pk=1).attribute_set.values()                                                                 
<QuerySet [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]>
```

I guess now I have to query Attr_1 for pk=1 and Attr_2 for pk=2?

Does the Attribute model has a relation to know if id=1 is in Attr_1 or Attr_2 model?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I wonder if a solution is achivieable by using contenttypes:
[Django model one foreign key to many tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528098/django-model-one-foreign-key-to-many-tables) I have to read and understand the technique.

It seems to me that [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) suits my needs.
Even though I don't like to use non-buildin libs and would love to know a solution by build in modules. I have no knowledge by hand to build a efficient queryset. Maybe my modeling is wrong?

But with polymorphic model i can query:

```
>> models.Object1.objects.get(pk=1).attribute_set.all()[0].url                                                                                      
'http://www.dot.com'
```

I just need to catch the type of object to not run into:

```
AttributeError: 'Attribute' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Hope somebody can help or explain the topic further even so I found something that works for me.

Comment: How are these Attributes in your results query created?

Comment: `Attr_1` and `Attribute`  models doesn't have any connections.

Comment: Nico-griffioen Not sure what you mean, but I created some data for each table via shell @SergeyPugach How can I make a reference from Attribute to the according derived class?