# How can I give foreign key to two models (so as to represent the activity logs)

Tags: django, foreign-keys

The problem is, I have to give foreign key reference to two different models so as to record the activity logs of the user

I have model named Activity Log to record the activities done by the user

```
class ActivityLog(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Build, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    # Target, (Optional) The object to which the activity was performed.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Actor  The object that performed the activity.
    action_object = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    # Action Object. (Optional) The object linked to the action itself.
    content = models.TextField()
    # Content of the activity
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

I need to give the target field with foreign key refering to two different models. Is it possible to use generic relations?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528098/django-model-one-foreign-key-to-many-tables) check it out and if you still had any questions, please ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - using multiple foreign key to the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697771/django-using-multiple-foreign-key-to-the-same-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use generic relations

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class ActivityLog(models.Model):
    target_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    target_id = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    target = GenericForeignKey('target_type', 'target_id')
    ...
    content = models.TextField()

# Usage   
target1 = Foo.objects.get(...)
target2 = Bar.objects.get(...)

ActivityLog(target=target1, content="Did something to foo").save()
ActivityLog(target=target2, content="Did something to bar").save()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and also I have some existing data along with this. When I tried to  update it with scripts  "ValueError: Cannot assign "<Build: 1>": "ActivityLog.target_type" must be a "ContentType" instance." I tried by updating the target_type and target_id.

Comment: You can manually change the target_type and target_id, but the target field is there so you don't have to do so. You can just pass any instance of any model to the GenericForeignKey field

Comment: While retrieving the data, Is there any special procedure that we have to look for?

Comment: Unfortunately, for retrieving data, then that's when you have to manually specify the target_type and target_id in queries. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: Thanks for the help, will try it out.

Comment: Is there any possible ways to compare the models from target_type? i,e how can we identify the models? (while retrieving the data)